# Retrieve Community Contact fields in force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community, lightning-data-service, force-recorddata

Is there a way to retrieve Community user's contact fields in force:recordData? This is my first lightning coming, and I'm not finding proper information on this.

I'm trying to display the logged in user's contact information in the community.

Answer (score 2):

`force:recordData` needs an id of a record to render the details of that record. So as long as you have the logged in User's details, you can retrieve the associated Contact Id from that using the `ContactId` field and pass it on to your lightning component.

To be able to fetch the Contact Id from the logged in User, you can use a query as below.

```
SELECT ContactId FROM User where Id = 'logged in user's id'
```

And then you you can utilize the Contact Id as retrieved above on your lightning component as:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="forceRecordCmp" recordId="{!v.contactId}" .... />
```

Comment: I'm starting down this path now and curious about the timing of the loading of this. can one component fetch the contact id from a controller and then update the force:recorddata recordid field? or would i need to have a parent component to get it first and pass it into a component once loaded? I also want to edit the record from the ui fields without binding, custom validation then say forcerecord.fields.set.field:value

Comment: The short answer to your queries is Yes. You can fetch the id in a component’s say init method and then have the id passed on to another component which has the force:recordData implementation.